# Как обновить данные mongodb без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

есть такой кусок кода который выводит данные из бд

````
    <% teamall.forEach(function (data) { %>
    <p>  <%= data.resultname %> => <%= data.name %> </p> 
    <% }) %>
    </ul>```

вопрос в том можно ли как-то сделать чтобы как только новые данные появлялись в бд
они появлялись на странице **без физического нажатия обновить страницу**
````

Comment: использовать ajax

Comment: entithat но на сколько я понимаю аякс на кнопку или собитие вешаеться, а у меня пустая страница с отчётами

Comment: ну на самом деле если данные тут риал-тайм, то либо сокеты, либо фетчить аяксом каждую секунду грубо

Comment: entithat пока как вариант сделал каждые 6 сек обнову через ajax.